# ECR image .NET 6 different CloudWatch log format

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

We are using lambda container image with .NET Core and we updated from *public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:5* to *public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:6*.

Now we get a different log format on CloudWatch when we call `Console.WriteLine()`:

*public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:5*

```
Hello World
```

*public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:6*

```
2021-12-23T13:36:12.694Z 89b35e73-2022-4XX5-86f9-eXXXXXXef3 info Hello World
```

Is there any way to remove unnecessary information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/973#issuecomment-969418893.

If you set an environment variable `AWS_LAMBDA_HANDLER_LOG_FORMAT` to `Unformatted` the Time, Request Id, and Log Level will not be outputted.

FYI - There's a feature request to control message formation programmatically. If that's important to you, you can +1 the Feature Request:https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/1000